# RequestError: Column "" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js

I have 2 tables using sequelize as follows

```
sequelize.define("campaign",{
        id:{
         type:Sequelize.INTEGER,
         autoIncrement:true,
         primaryKey:true,
         allowNull:false
        },
        title:{
            type:Sequelize.STRING
        },
        description:{
            type:Sequelize.STRING
        },
        targetamount:{
            type:Sequelize.INTEGER
        },
        startdate:{
            type:Sequelize.DATE
        },
        enddate:{
            type:Sequelize.DATE
            
        }
    });
```

```
sequelize.define("transaction",{
        id:{
         type:Sequelize.INTEGER,
         autoIncrement:true,
         primaryKey:true,
         allowNull:false
        },
        date:{
            type:Sequelize.DATE
        },
        amount:{
            type:Sequelize.INTEGER
        },
        notes:{
            type:Sequelize.STRING
        }
    });
```

and table *transaction* associated with *campaign* as

```
db.Transactions.belongsTo(db.Campaigns);
db.Campaigns.hasMany(db.Transactions,{as:"campaign"});
```

Now I am trying to get all the campaigns with sum of amounts collected from the transactions using the below code

```
    const pageSize = 10000;
    const offset = 0;
    Transactions.findAndCountAll({
        attributes: [[Sequelize.fn('sum', Sequelize.col('amount')), 'total']],
        group:['campaignId'],
        limit:pageSize,
        offset:offset
    }).then(async (data)=>{
        ///
    });
```

but this is giving the error,

*RequestError: Column "transactions.id" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.*

It seems sequelize returning 'id' column by default.
how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the SQL that's being generated under-the-hood is invalid.

Order is being applied because you're asking for `limit` and `offset` (usually used for paging) which *requires ordering* to be deterministic.

To mitigate this you can either:

1. remove the `limit` and `offset`
2. provide an explicit `ORDER BY` that is either in your grouping (`campaignId`) or the aggregate (`total`)

Something like this, perhaps?

```js
const pageSize = 10000;
const offset = 0;
Transactions.findAndCountAll({
    attributes: [[Sequelize.fn('sum', Sequelize.col('amount')), 'total']],
    group:['campaignId'],
    limit:pageSize,
    offset:offset,
    order: ['campaignId']
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I was missing this point.